# ImportError: cannot import name (hidden circular import?)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

`app/__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

from views import IndexView


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('app.config')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# routing
app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=IndexView.as_view('show_posts'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

`app/models.py`

```
import datetime

from app import db


class Article(db.Model):
    # some fields


class Author(db.Model):
    # some more fields
```

`app/seed.py`

```
from app.models import Author, Article
from app import db


author1 = Author('guy 1')
author2 = Author('guy 2')
article1 = Article(authors=[author1, author2], contents='dsafda')
article1 = Article(authors=[author1], contents='vcxzcvz')

db.session.add(author1)
db.session.add(author2)
db.session.add(article1)
db.session.add(article1)
db.session.commit()
```

I'm trying to run `python -m app.manage_scripts.seed` from the level above `app` and I'm getting the error mentioned in the title. I don't see a circular import problem in my code, but maybe I'm just overlooking something?

Edit:

Console output is:

`(_env) E:\code\python\flask_blog>python -m app.manage_scripts.seed
E:\code\python\flask_blog\_env\Scripts\python.exe: cannot import name db`

Comment: Please add the full error traceback!

Comment: There's no more of a traceback than I've written in this post topic :)

Comment: The db is in your __init__.py are you sure you even need to import it?

Comment: Ok, I've commented out the import db statement in seed.py, but I'm still getting this error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by making some imports locally. Working version of the code (`app/__init__.py`):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy


def create_routes(app):
    from views import IndexView
    app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=IndexView.as_view('show_posts'))


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('app.config')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_routes(app)

    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```